# Can't type in tui image editor

Tags: toast-ui-image-editor

I'm integrating tui image editor on my project but I'm facing a problem when I try to type. The image editor is inside a modal and I think it has to do something with that but I don't know what. Everything works fine except when I try to add a text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't suppose you ever figured this out? I've got the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have tested using react-bootstrap using modal and it works. set enforceFocus to false. like the code below

```
<Modal enforceFocus={false}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, here is some possible solution:

[Unable to edit text field](https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor/issues/354)

In my case, I was using bootstrap modal and I set the 'data-bs-focus' to 'false'. And it worked. Like below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" data-bs-focus="false" role="dialog">
```